# Set background to div tag, materialize.css

Tags: html, css, forms, background, materialize

Using materialize.css (http://materializecss.com), need set image as background of input form, so image should resize when window will be resized. Now it looks like: when browser window half-screen size like this:[image]
and when browser window maximised it looks crap:[image]
I hope you'll get idea, sorry for my english.
So I need proper html code for that form.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** My html code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row col s12">
        <div class="row col s8 offset-s2 white z-depth-3">

            <div style='float: left; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background: url("../static/assets/images/envelope.png") center center no-repeat;' class="col s12">

                <div class="row">
                    <h5 class="center">Адрес для получения посылки:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s5 offset-s1">
                        <input id="firstName" type="text" class="validate"/>
                        <label for="firstName">Имя</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s5">
                        <input id="lastName" type="text" class="validate"/>
                        <label for="lastName">Фамилия</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s5 offset-s1">
                        <input id="country" type="text" class="validate"/>
                        <label for="country">Страна</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s5">
                        <input id="zipCode" type="text" class="validate"/>
                        <label for="zipCode">Индекс</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s5 offset-s1">
                        <input id="city" type="text" class="validate"/>
                        <label for="city">Город</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s5">
                        <input id="street" type="text" class="validate"/>
                        <label for="street">Улица</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s2 offset-s1">
                        <input id="house" type="text" class="validate"/>
                        <label for="house">Дом</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s2">
                        <input id="room" type="text" class="validate"/>
                        <label for="room">Квартира</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row center">
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">send</i>Сохранить</a>
                    <br/>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: we cant debug img you should provide some code

Answer (score 0):

min-width in CSS for your image?

```
<div style='min-width: XXXpx; float: left; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background: url("../static/assets/images/envelope.png") center center no-repeat;' class="col s12">
```

where XXX is width of your content + about 30px for image border.